White bars when resizing the window

I am trying to create a window with SDL3 using the following code
#include "SDL3/SDL.h"
#include "SDL3/SDL_system.h"

int main(){
    unsigned int sdlFlags = 0;
    sdlFlags |= SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE;
    sdlFlags |= SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS;
    sdlWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(InTitle, InWidth, InHeight, sdlFlags);
    while(true){
        SDL_PollEvent(&sdlEvent);
        switch (sdlEvent.type)
        {
            case SDL_EVENT_WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUESTED:  break;
        }

    }
}

But when you try to resize the window, white stripes appear that do not disappear
The problem arose when switching from SDL2 to SDL3

Do you draw anything at all to the window? Also a [mcve] would be nice.

Added  minimal reproducible example

Welp, you're not drawing anything. Start drawing stuff, and it will overwrite that white line after the resize is done.

The real problem was that I didn't draw anything in the window, thanks

Clear the window contents. This could be done with a rendering API like Vulkan or indirectly with SDL's own abstract rendering features, expanding the original question's code something like this:
#include "SDL3/SDL.h"
#include "SDL3/SDL_system.h"

int main(){
    unsigned int sdlFlags = 0;
    sdlFlags |= SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE;
    sdlFlags |= SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS;
    SDL_Window* sdlWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(InTitle, InWidth, InHeight, sdlFlags);
    SDL_Renderer* sdlRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(sdlwindow, NULL);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(sdlRenderer, 0, 0, 0, 255); // opaque black

    while(true){
        SDL_PollEvent(&sdlEvent);
        switch (sdlEvent.type)
        {
            case SDL_EVENT_WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUESTED:  break;
        }
        // Draw the window contents, starting by clearing it:
        SDL_RenderClear(sdlRenderer);
        // Draw stuff...
        // Show the rendered contents in the window:
        SDL_RenderPresent(sdlRenderer);

    }
}

Untested example derived from OP's code and from this official example: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL3/SDL_RenderClear
